# Openstack: how to make this bridge mapping?

Tags: openstack

I had a running openstack server, works fine but only with external-net(extnet, mapped to br-ex)
I want to use the internal net(intnet) but is not mapped to br-int.
How to map it?
I have tried to edit the packstack conf

```
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=extnet:br-ex,intnet:br-int
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGE_IFACES=br-ex:eno1,br-int:eno2
```

but when apply with

```
packstack --answer-file `date +"%d.%m.%y"`.conf
```

it correct the answer file and my modify is removed

```
# Comma-separated list of bridge mappings for the OpenStack
# Networking Open Virtual Network plugin. Each tuple in the list must
# be in the format <physical_network>:<ovs_bridge>. Example: physnet1
# :br-eth1,physnet2:br-eth2,physnet3:br-eth3
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=extnet:br-ex

# Comma-separated list of colon-separated Open vSwitch
# <bridge>:<interface> pairs. The interface will be added to the
# associated bridge. If you desire the bridge to be persistent a value
# must be added to this directive, also
# CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS must be set in order to create
# the proper port. This can be achieved from the command line by
# issuing the following command: packstack --allinone --os-neutron-
# ovn-bridge-mappings=ext-net:br-ex --os-neutron-ovn-bridge-interfaces
# =br-ex:eth0
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGE_IFACES=
```

and my syntax seems to be correct.
My question is: how to manually add the mapping?
I tried this way

```
vim /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini
bridge_mappings = extnet:br-ex,intnet:br-int
```

and after restart neutron, the istances configured to use intnet failed with message

```
 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-707b1004-ee7c-4449-b9f7-6465862bb8a8 2d88a48b96004d47bba6af01ef0fbd2c 9daaa34268c846c5aad322a7765602ce - default default] Failed to bind port eb533bc8-75b4-4852-8f85-de57a84c64a4 on host virtuale.myhost.priv for vnic_type normal using segments [{'network_id': 'ba05def0-580e-4019-97e7-1a8779be2184', 'segmentation_id': None, 'physical_network': u'intnet', 'id': 'c28bc550-afb5-49d0-bf82-c9310ae42c2e', 'network_type': u'flat'}]
```

So I think the mapping is not working, of course if I use extnet the istance start.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found, using the new OVN as a mechanism, instead of OVS.
I set those variables on answer file.

```
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_MECHANISM_DRIVERS=ovn
CONFIG_NEUTRON_L2_AGENT=ovn
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=extnet:br-ex,intnet:br-int
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGE_IFACES=br-ex:eno1,br-int:eno2
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGES_COMPUTE=br-ex
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_EXTERNAL_PHYSNET=extnet
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_TUNNEL_IF=
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_TUNNEL_SUBNETS=
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_TYPE_DRIVERS=vxlan,flat,geneve
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPES=vxlan,geneve
```

All ok.

Comment: Hi! Could you share interfaces config?

Answer (score 0):

Do You maybe remember what was config for your NICs? I have 4x1GB + 2x10GB NICs in my HP DL580 (for 500 $USD xD), have configured them as such.

1GB, 2x Public network NICs (to access internet)

[image]

1gb NIC that act as router for the internal network (darn, now I remember I forgot to set DHCP for that).

[image]

1GB, NIC that is defined but without address

[image]

10GB, NIC

[image]

For now I want to set only one node. When it will work, I will add two more nodes as compute ones.

[image]

So then I should have config like

```
CONFIG_SSL_CERT_SUBJECT_CN: node000
CONFIG_CINDER_VOLUME_NAME: cinder-volumes
CONFIG_CINDER_VOLUMES_SIZE: 20G
CONFIG_NEUTRON_L2_AGENT: ovn
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_MECHANISM_DRIVERS: ovn
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_TYPE_DRIVERS: vxlan,flat,geneve
CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPES: vxlan,geneve
CONFIG_NEUTRON_L3_EXT_BRIDGE: 'br-ex'
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_TUNNEL_IF: ''  
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS: 'extnet:br-ex,intnet:br-in' 
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGE_IFACES: 'br-ex:net1,br-in:unet0'
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_BRIDGES_COMPUTE: 'br-in'    # when enabled vlan or flat
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVN_EXTERNAL_PHYSNET: 'extnet'    # when enabled demo
CONFIG_PROVISION_DEMO: "n"
CONFIG_PROVISION_TEMPEST: "n"
```

Is there anything else to do?

EDIT: I was following that [enter link description here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/455603), but kinda failed, and will have to try again.

Comment: Is impossible that I remind the configuration exactly because i'm over one year without using Openstack. I only remind I have disable network-manager and configure ovn instead of ovs, so I can only say to google and search for configure ovn network openstack.

Comment: I don't know if this can help you, but I will put the ovs configuration taken from my notes. I'm not test it recently because as I said i'm not using openstack since one year. https://pastebin.com/raw/bhDwRtEV

Comment: I forgot, remind to disable network manager and use the classical network configuration style because with NM you will get a lot of troubles with OVS and OVN openstack networking

Comment: Thanks, this are exactly NIC configs I wanted before :D

Comment: Hmm did You use those OVS configs with OVN Openstack setup?

Comment: Yes, I called OVS because devicetype=ovn didn't exist. So you must use "devicetype=ovs" even if use ovn. Of course I repeat: i test it last time one year ago so it can work or it can not work.

Comment: damn, i will stick to kolla-ansible then, it require bit more stuff but its much effective in the end